# How to interface a Maven project with Jacoco/codecov on CircleCI?

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, circleci

I have [this repository](https://github.com/coderodde/IndexedLinkedList) and cannot make test coverage via Jacoco and put those test coverage files in codecov.

My attempt is:

```yaml
version: 2.1
orbs:
  codecov: codecov/codecov@3.3.0
workflows:
  upload-to-codecov:
    jobs:
      - checkout
      - codecov/upload
```

which fails on builds:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
mvn test
CircleCI received exit code 127
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: _"fails"_ how, specifically? What's it supposed to be uploading, given all it seems to have done by that point is check out the repo?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just added the output at CircleCI.

Comment: Please give a [mre], we've no idea what's in the repo - presumably you expect `mvn test` to exit 0, but we can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

In the [build #58](https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/coderodde/IndexedLinkedList/71/workflows/3d58a9c5-17ad-4563-9040-3c673b5eec74/jobs/58/parallel-runs/0/steps/0-102) you have exit code 127, if log is checked, then it shows:

```
/bin/bash: mvn: command not found

Exited with code exit status 127
```

Try to include [maven-wrapper](https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/) into your repository, so you would not need to install mvn on each build and on whichever env you are running.